# How to set a default for a zope.schema.list of a dexterity content type?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

This is the definition of a dexterity content type in Plone:

```
  <schema>
    <field name="categories" type="zope.schema.List">
      <description>Each line one category</description>
      <required>True</required>
      <title>Categories</title>
      <default>[u'General', ]</default>
      <value_type type="zope.schema.TextLine"></value_type>
      <missing_value>()</missing_value>
    </field>
  </schema>
```

How does the default value has to be declared? I would expect that a list has to be provided in this way above. But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not supposed to provide a manually serialized list, just create a list of XML elements. Use the following format:

```
  <default>
    <element>General</element>
    <element>Specific</element>
  </default>
```

Hint: the easiest way to find the right format is to use the Dexterity inline schema editor, so you can set your default value in the UI, and then you just need to switch to "Edit XML Field model" to get the resulting XML source.